# How should I connect a new ceiling fan which is controlled by a remote?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am replacing an existing ceiling fan whose light was controlled by a wall switch & fan by the chain.  The new fan is controlled by a remote only, no chains.

There are 4 wires coming from the ceiling electrical box: white, black, pink & bare. There are only 3 wires to the input side of the remote: white, black, & ground.

The wall switch has only 2 wires: black & pink. I know that the wall switch must be "on" to permit the remote/fan to operate.

What wires from the ceiling do I need to connect to the input side of the remote? I already tried connecting the pink to white & black to black without success.  I connected the output side of the remote to the fan per the instructions with the fan.

Answer (score 2):

Connect the white wire to the white wire.

If you want the wall switch to turn off the light/fan, then hook the pink wire in the box to the black wire on your controller. If you want to prevent the switch from turning off the light/fan then connect black to black.

Which ever wire you don't use should be capped with a spare wire nut and wrapped with electrical tape.

Comment: Used the wall switch method, connecting the pink wire in the box to the black wire on the controller. Works! Thank-you

Answer (score 2):

A/C devices like lights and fan motors need to be connected to a "hot" (live) wire and a "neutral" (normally white) wire to operate. The ground wire is for safety.

At your wall box you have a black and a pink wire. These are most likely a black "hot" and a pink "switched hot". A switched hot is only hot when your wall switch is ON, it delivers live power to the ceiling box. Remember, a switch just makes or breaks a hot wire, no neutral wire hooks to the switch, that is why there is no white wire at the wall box.

At your ceiling box you have:
- a black wire, this is most likely a "hot" wire (you can confirm with an electrical tester) 
- a pink wire, this is most likely the "switched hot" from your wall box that can be turned on or off with a switch installed in the wall box.
- a white wire, this is most likely the neutral wire.
- a bare wire, this is a ground wire.

Assuming the above is true:
At the ceiling box- white to white, black to black, bare to ground. This will give constant power to your appliance and "remote only" control. Cap off the wires in the wall box and cover with a blank plate as the switch will no longer be of any use.

OR
At the ceiling box- white to white, pink to black, bare to ground. This will give you switched power to the appliance. Re-install the wall switch at the wall box. This will allow you to control the appliance with the remote only when the wall switch is turned on.

remember- never work with live power, disconnect power at the breaker or fuse panel. Many different wire colors and configurations may exist, it is always best to confirm with an electrical tester or hire a qualified electrician.

Comment: Used your second method for using the wall switch, connected the pink to black, white to white, bare to ground. Fan & Light operate fine. Thanks!!